# Matlab: histogram of object's color pixels based on the hue values

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, object-detection

I'm new to DIP, but I need to reproduce the following histogram. 
[image]

When I use the simple code below, it cannot generate the same figure!

```
img1 = imread('013.png');  
figure(1), imshow(img1)
img_hsv = rgb2hsv(img1);
imhist(img_hsv(:,:,1))
```

Here is the original image

[image]

and the image of the yellow ball segmented.

[image]

### **Edit After Raviteja Narra's ANSWER:**

But when I use a similar code in Matlab, I get the following figure

```
img1 = imread('img.png');  
img_hsv = rgb2hsv(img1);
hue_img = img_hsv(:,:,1)
array = hue_img(find(hue_img > 0.1))
hist(array, 20)
```

My hue values are in range 0.11-0.17, and it seems that the bins of my histogram are mirrored versions of Raviteja's plot! What's the reason for this strange plot?

### [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is almost all the pixels in the image have hue value 0. So the histogram is dominated by that. So, the result just looks like it has a big spike at 0. To see the expected histogram, create a new array by removing the 0 values from the original hue_img. This will show a gaussian distribution. Here is the python code for this.

```
img = cv2.imread(r"\img.png") 
rgb_img = img 
hsv_img = rgb2hsv(rgb_img) 
hue_img = hsv_img[:, :, 0] 
array = hue_img[np.where(hue_img > 0.1)] 
plt.hist(array,bins=100)
```

The image would look like this.
[image]

Comment: Please see this video: https://www.coursera.org/lecture/robotics-learning/1-2-1-1d-gaussian-distribution-ILMmj

Comment: Thank you for comment. Could you please edit your answer with this python code and the resulting figure?

Comment: please read my edited post. My hue values are in range 0.11-0.17,  and it seems that the bins of my histogram are mirrored versions of your plot! What's the reason for this strange plot?

Comment: I am not quite sure why this is, but there is one observation that I made, the output you got is a mirror image of what I got.